# Is it possible to select everything from a MySQL database meanwhile applying a function to a specific column?

Tags: mysql

Given a database table which is built like so:

```
| id | unique_id                            | display_name    | ip_address    | updated_at       | created_at       |
|----|--------------------------------------|-----------------|---------------|------------------|------------------|
| 1  | 768ef24f-79ab-481e-b50f-45b0466933c1 | SimpleAuthority | *binary data* | *some timestamp* | *some timestamp* |
| 2  | 069a79f4-44e9-4726-a5be-fca90e38aaf5 | Notch           | *binary data* | *some timestamp* | *some timestamp* |
```

I know that I can `SELECT` each column explicitly and apply `INET6_NTOA` on `ip_address`:

```
SELECT id, unique_id, display_name, INET6_NTOA(ip_address), updated_at, created_at FROM users WHERE unique_id='768ef24f-79ab-481e-b50f-45b0466933c1';
```

however, that seems like too much work where without having that binary encoded data in there at all I could simply use a `*`:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE unique_id='768ef24f-79ab-481e-b50f-45b0466933c1';
```

Can I `SELECT` all this data using a query, while decoding that **binary data** in the `ip_address` column using `INET6_NTOA`?

Comment: You can simply use `SELECT *, INET6_NTOA(ip_address) FROM users`

Comment: @mauris Wow, that was too easy. However, now I see in the returned result set that there is an ip_address column holding the binary data and a column named INET6_NTOA(ip_address) containing the decoded data. Is this normal? Thanks, by the way!

Comment: yes it is. you can rename the result of the function too. `SELECT *, INET6_NTOA(ip_address) as ip FROM users`

Comment: @mauris OK! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT *, INET6_NTOA(ip_address) FROM users WHERE unique_id='768ef24f-79ab-481e-b50f-45b0466933c1';
```